# Php Simple dom parser Unable to get google drive folder names

Tags: php, parsing, dom

Using Php simple dom parser library i want to get all the folder names of the google drive . By using inspect element i saw all folders have `class="l-Ab-T-r"`. So i am trying to extract all folder names by using above class but i get nothing . Plesae help . Here i smy full code .

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: pankaj
 * Date: 11/2/2018
 * Time: 10:01 PM
 */
require "simple_html_dom.php";
$html = file_get_html("https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2t-Tmujl-IbeGFOUmo0aWVIeEU");
foreach ($html->find('div[class="l-Ab-T-r"]') as $folderName){
    echo $folderName."<br/>";
}
```